# top showing huge number in place of memory percentage

Tags: memory, top, ram

Today I decided to run `top` on my Arch Linux laptop, to be greeted with this:

[image: what even]

In particular, this bothers me:

[image: even what-er]

`GiB Mem :225809113546752.0/7.791`

This number doesn't change with the actual memory consumption.

Does anyone have any idea why this occurs?

Comment: What output of this command: `cat /proc/meminfo | grep Mem`?

Comment: This is obviously a bug, report it to the maintainers of your distribution.

Comment: Did you have the same problem with `htop` command?

Comment: @MiniMax `MemTotal:        8169176 kB
MemFree:          450528 kB
MemAvailable:    1893480 kB` (seems correct)

Comment: @GAD3R No, I did not.

Comment: @jasonwryan This is an Arch Linux bug, it deserves the Arch Linux tag.

Comment: No, it is an [upstream bug](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/issues/64).

Comment: @jasonwryan It has been fixed and is now an issue in Arch Linux because the package has not yet been rebuilt. Verify this by install procps-ng-git from the AUR.

Comment: The bug is an upstream one: it exists in *every* distro with that version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is known and fixed already - [top: protect against the anomalous 'Mem' graph display](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/commit/a2ceb95e2a7d5bf0270f0d342d2edb560f5cfcf4)

> Until this patch, top falsely assumed that there would always be some
>   (small) amount of physical memory after subtracting 'used' and
>   'available' from the total. But as the issue referenced below attests,
>   a sum of 'used' and 'available' might exceed that total memory amount.

The bug was patched a month ago, but the Arch Linux's `procps-ng` package was built in the 10.07.2016. So, the simple system upgrade won't help in this case.

**You have two ways to solve this problem at least:**

1. Building the last version of the `procps-ng` from the source.
2. Using `htop` or another analog for system monitoring.